# New Microsoft Remote Desktop App (version 8) - 'the requested session access is denied'

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

The newest Microsoft Remote Desktop app (v 8.0.24255) refuses to connect to a terminal server I use - username and password are accepted but then the server reports 'The requested session access is denied'.

Whereas the old Remote Desktop app I was using (v 2.1.1) still works just fine...

Any ideas on how to find the problem?

Comment: FYI, it seems the new client is buggy as hell. I routinely have to force quit the app to just get it to connect sometimes when I have previously connected to another server. Using the same version as you.

Comment: I am posting here about this issue: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/da44a4c0-0627-44d9-8a37-e3741b4c0697/denied-access-to-the-server-in-rdp-803-app-with-mac-os-maverick?forum=winRDc Did you solve the issue?

Comment: No real solution, except that logging in first with 2.1.1 , then resuming a logged session with 8.0.2 seems to work! Crazy.